# Show fullscreen popup with addressbar in javascript

Tags: javascript, web

I want to show a popup window in full screen with only the address bar visible on Top. The minimize and Close button should also be not visible. Currently I am using the following code which enables me to go in full screen mode in IE 9 but does not show the address bar even though location=1

```
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=1,menubar=1,location=0,directories=1,status=0,channelmode=0,fullscreen=1')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to only show the navigation bar in full screen as of yet - or at least not from what I can find.

If this is the case, you'll want to recreate the address bar programmatically, and then reset your location through JavaScript when you use the address bar. You can use CSS styles to make this look more or less like the standard bar depending on your needs.

I've fleshed out the JS more in the following example; on the form's `submit` event you can use `window.location.href` to cause a redirect within the browser. The input will likely need to be heavily manipulated to get it to be a working url (e.g. making sure that it's a valid address before you reset their location).

I would also consider adding the kind of functionality we find in common browsers where a query not treated as a URL is instead treated as a search. You can use the Google Web API for this: https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/

You won't have access to browser history for autocomplete, which could possibly be solved by keeping a library of commonly visited sites and using an autocomplete library to assist you.

Though this doesn't directly answer your question, I hope that it can be of some help to you.

```
HTML
<div class="modal">
  <form>
    <input type="text"></input>
  </form>
</div>


JS

(function(){

document.getElementById("nav-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    var val = document.getElementById("nav-bar").value;
    //parse and execute the navigation command
    //in here, we would check to make sure it's valid, etc.
    //and format it to make sure it's a working url
    //and keep a case for if it's not a valid url,
    //in which case you can leverage the google search api
    window.location.href = val;
});

}(window));
```

JS Fiddle showing bare bones of above: http://jsfiddle.net/x8heK/2/